# How to create thread safe GetEventHandler()?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
public partial class JobDataDuplicatorForm : Form
{
    public JobDataDuplicatorForm(IJobDataDuplicatorEngine engine)
    {
        _engine.CopyStartedEvent += GetEventHandler(OnCopyStarted);
        _engine.CopyEndedEvent += GetEventHandler(OnCopyEnded);
        ...
    }

    private static EventHandler GetEventHandler(Action action)
    {
        return (sender, args) => action();
    }

    private void OnCopyStarted()
    {
        copyStatus.Text = "Copy progress: ";
        generateButton.Enabled = false; // Cross-thread operation not valid
    }
}
```

I have the following exception:

```
Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 
'generateButton' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

Can I fix the exception by changing `GetEventHandler()` instead of wrapping each button in different places like this

`Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
       generateButton.Enabled = false; 
       });` ?

How can I do this?

Comment: By any chance are you calling `JobDataDuplicatorForm(IJobDataDuplicatorEngine engine)` from a background thread initially?

Comment: Updated, looks like I always execute old variant. But how??

Comment: are you just trying to enable and disable the buttons?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes

Comment: @Sorceri In this case - yes. But I have different cases. And I don't want to wrap each cases, I want to wrap it ones in the `GetEventHandler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments you said you call `JobDataDuplicatorForm(IJobDataDuplicatorEngine engine)` from a background thread.

Your class is a `Form`, any windows controls (Which includes Form) must be initially created on the UI thread or things like `Invoke` and `InvokeRequired` break. Whatever code is calling the constructor of `JobDataDuplicatorForm` must do that call from the UI thread.